# How can I add a string into function in this situation php?

Tags: javascript, php, buddypress

I am trying to add some feature into a plugin call buddypress first-letter-avatar. It assign avatar base on username's first letter, however, I would like to customize it. I want it also base on usename's gender. I want to add a string $gender into the following function,  I am trying to add $gender into this code, in what way I can achieve that or where I should I look at this code and start to customized it? appreciate.

```html
<?php
private function choose_custom_avatar($username, $size, $alt = '', $gender){
  $id=//get user_id, dont know how to get it yet
  $gender=bp_get_profile_field_data('Gender', $id);//

  // get picture filename (and lowercase it) from commenter name:
  //var_dump($username);
  $file_name = substr($username, $this->letter_index, 1); // get one letter counting from letter_index
  $file_name = strtolower($file_name); // lowercase it...
  // if, for some reason, the result is empty, set file_name to default unknown image:
  if (empty($file_name)){
   $file_name = $this->image_unknown;
  }

  // create array with allowed character range (in this case it is a-z range):
  $allowed_chars = range('a', 'z');
  
  // check if the file name meets the requirement; if it doesn't - set it to unknown
  if (!in_array($file_name, $allowed_chars)){
   $file_name = $this->image_unknown;
  }
  
  
  
  // detect most appropriate size based on WP avatar size:
  if ($size <= 48 && $gender=='Female') $custom_avatar_size = '48';
  else if ($size > 48 && $size <= 96 && $gender=='Female') $custom_avatar_size = '96';
  else if ($size > 96 && $size <= 128 && $gender=='Female') $custom_avatar_size = '128';
  else if ($size > 128 && $size <= 256 && $gender=='Female') $custom_avatar_size = '256';
  else if ($size <= 48 && $gender=='Male') $custom_avatar_size = '1';
  else if ($size > 48 && $size <= 96 && $gender=='Male') $custom_avatar_size = '2';
  else if ($size > 96 && $size <= 128 && $gender=='Male') $custom_avatar_size = '3';
  else if ($size > 128 && $size <= 256 && $gender=='Male') $custom_avatar_size = '4';
  else $custom_avatar_size = '512';
 

  // create file path - avatar_path variable will look something like this:
  // http://yourblog.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-first-letter-avatar/images/default/96/k.png):
  $avatar_uri =
   plugins_url() . '/'
   . dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)) . '/'
   . self::BPFLA_IMAGES_PATH . '/'
   . $this->avatar_set . '/'
   . $custom_avatar_size . '/'
   . $file_name . '.'
   . $this->images_format;

  // output the final HTML img code:
  return $this->output_img($avatar_uri, $size, $alt);
 }
 


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you're trying to pass the `$gender` variable as a parameter to the function and then in line 3 you're defining that very variable in the function:

```
private function choose_custom_avatar($username, $size, $alt = '', $gender){
        $id=//get user_id, dont know how to get it yet
        $gender=bp_get_profile_field_data('Gender', $id);//
```

This is not the way to do it. Instead, pass a variable, say `$gen` as parameter, and then redifine the `$gender` variable in the function depending on whether a gender parameter is passed or not:

```
private function choose_custom_avatar($username, $size, $alt = '', $gen=null){
        $id=//get user_id, dont know how to get it yet
        $gen !== '' ? $gender = $gen : $gender=bp_get_profile_field_data('Gender', $id);
```

This way, you don't have to change your code much and it will work as before if the `$gen` parameter is not passed.